# Unreachable Statement with a JFrame

Tags: jframe

I have created a program to display red and black boxes. When I compile it there is an error saying that the variable I used to declare for my JFrame to set visible is an unreachable statement. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame();
        theGUI.setTitle("Colour");
        theGUI.setSize(300, 300);
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));   
        Color color1 = Color.black;
        Color color2 = Color.red;
        for (int i = 1; 1 <= 64; i++){
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            //Alternate colors on a row
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                panel.setBackground(color1);
            else
                panel.setBackground(color2);
            pane.add(panel);
            // at the end of a row start next row on the other color1
            if ( i % 8 == 0){
                Color temp = color1;
                color1 = color2;
                color2 = temp;

            }

        }
    theGUI.setVisible(true);    

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have figured it out by now. The loop condition is wrong...says 1 <= 64, should be i <= 64...
/Mattias

Comment: Ah yeah I am stupid thank you very much. I am new to all this.